# Angular2 Error on dependency parsing. Possible cause - recent package update

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to debug an angular 2 application using Visual Studio Code and NPM start from the command line (as an Admin).  Does anyone recognize this error and know how to fix it?  I am not sure if this is enough info, I can provide it if you tell me what to provide.  I think it has to do with a package update because it was working originally.  I appreciate any help!  Here is the output/error:

```
C:\Repos\MyWebSite>npm start

> my-angular-template@1.0.0 start C:\Repos\MyWebSite
> concurrently "node" "npm run tsc:w" "gulp"

[1]
[1] > my-angular-template@1.0.0 tsc:w C:\Repos\MyWebSite
[1] > tsc -w
[1]
[2] [10:25:19]
[2] Using gulpfile C:\Repos\MyWebSite\gulpfile.js
[2] [10:25:19]
[2] Starting 'default'...
[2] [10:25:19]
[2] Starting 'build'...
[2] [10:25:19] Starting 'jspm-bundle-common'...
[2] [10:25:20]
[2] Starting 'scss'...
[2] [10:25:20]
[2] Starting 'tslint'...
[2] [10:25:20] Finished 'tslint' after 77 µs
[2] [10:25:20] Starting 'browserSync'...
[2] [10:25:20]
[2] Finished 'browserSync' after 89 ms
[2] events.js:141
[2]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[2]       ^
[2]
[2] Error on dependency parsing for app/app.component.html at file:///C:/Repos/MyWebSite/app/app.component.html
[2]     (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
[2]     SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
[2]         at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
[2]         at SystemJSNodeLoader.loader.instantiate (C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\compilers\amd.js:292:30)
[2]         at SystemJSNodeLoader.loader.instantiate (C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\compilers\esm.js:54:32)
[2]         at C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\trace.js:533:25
[2]         at tryCatcher (C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
[2]         at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:510:31)
[2]         at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:567:18)
[2]         at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:612:10)
[2]         at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:691:18)
[2]         at Async._drainQueue (C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
[2]         at Async._drainQueues (C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
[2]         at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Repos\MyWebSite\node_modules\systemjs-builder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
[2]         at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
[2]     Evaluating C:/Repos/MyWebSite/app/app.component.html
[2] gulp exited with code 1
```

Comment: Check SystemJS configuration, anything that might have changed there or a new package added. From the error it looks like instead of loading a js file it gets some html, hence "unexpected token <".

Comment: when i see angled brackets in the error, the first thing I think of is that its a server-side error. Have you inspected the network traffic,and verified that its returning a 200 OK status code?